# Missing clause group by DBF FoxPro

Tags: c#, foxpro, dbf

I have this query in C# and I have tried to add `group by` for all non-aggregate values but it does not function.

I have 3 tables:

1. First table I have `assemblyno`, `part_no`, `rout_no` (unique), `wo_no`, etc...
2. On the second I have `wo_no` (same from table 1) and `job_no`, this is the "link" table between 1 and 3
3. And third table the `job_no` (same as second table) with `order_val`

Have to extract for a given `rout_no` in 1st table the `max(order_val)` on the third table using the second table that will link `wo_no` and `job_no`...
I hope is more clear.

Error:

> Additional information: SQL: GROUP BY clause is missing or invalid.

```
        sql = string.Format(@" SELECT t1.assemblyno, t1.level, t1.wo_no, t1.rout_no, t1.due_date, t1.printed, t1.rev_no, t2.lot, t2.po, t2.qty_due, t3.comment, t3.jobno, MAX(t3.order_val), t3.part_no,t3.po,t3.price, t3.qty_order, t3.quote_no, t3.rev_no 
    FROM ('{0}') t1 
    LEFT JOIN ('{1}') t2 
    on t1.wo_no = 2.wo_no 
    LEFT JOIN ('{2}') t3 
    on t2.jobno = t3.jobno 
    GROUP BY  t1.assemblyno, t1.level, t1.wo_no, t1.rout_no, t1.due_date, t1.printed, t1.rev_no, t2.lot, t2.po, t2.qty_due, t3.comment, t3.jobno,t3.part_no,t3.po,t3.price, t3.qty_order, t3.quote_no, t3.rev_no 
WHERE t1.rout_no=" + "\'" + rNum + "\'" + ";", databaseTable_WOROUTH, databaseTable_WOJOBS, databaseTable_SOMAST);
```

Comment: Your query does not contain a group by clause. Please show your attempt including the group by clause. And may I ask why you are using a FoxPro DBF? FoxPro is essentially dead technology, and if you can, you should avoid it.

Comment: Indeed is a dead technologies but where I work is a must. I have posted with group statement

Comment: It is not a good way of writing queries in C# (be it for Foxpro or any other backend - makes the query unreadable if nothing else like SQL injection). The problem has nothing to do with the backend being Foxpro, it would be the case with any backend. If you are using aggregation you need "group by". In your case however just listing all non-aggregate would likely simply return excess information that you don't want. Please share the structures, plus what you really need. For example jobno field, is that unique in T3? If not, given a job how do determine the unique id for given order_val?

Comment: I now see your edited query and it likely simply would return the information that you don't want (you are asking for the max(order_val) where all other columns are distinct).

Comment: I learn new things but I have to fix old things - that are new for moment :)

Comment: At a quick glance I can see that the 'GROUP BY' clause comes before the 'WHERE' which is invalid in pretty much every SQL implementation out there. Put them in inverse order. BTW, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Alejandro, he is asking for Foxpro (or VFP). That is valid in foxpro's implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not going to share your structures and more info. Based on only what we have, probably this is what you are looking for:

```
    sql = string.Format(@" SELECT 
        t1.assemblyno, t1.level, t1.wo_no, t1.rout_no, 
        t1.due_date, t1.printed, t1.rev_no, t2.lot, t2.po, t2.qty_due, 
        t3.comment, t3.jobno, MAX(t3.order_val), t3.part_no,t3.po,t3.price, t3.qty_order,
        t3.quote_no, t3.rev_no 
        FROM ('{0}') t1 
        LEFT JOIN ('{1}') t2  on t1.wo_no = 2.wo_no 
        LEFT JOIN (
    select * from ('{2}') tmp1
    inner join  
    (select jobNo, max(order_val) as order_val from ('{2}') group by jobNo) tmp2
    on tmp1.JobNo = tmp2.JobNo and tmp1.Order_Val=tmp2.Order_val
        ) t3 
        on t2.jobno = t3.jobno 
    WHERE t1.rout_no=?", databaseTable_WOROUTH, databaseTable_WOJOBS, databaseTable_SOMAST);

//cmd.Parameters.Add("@rnum", OleDbType.Char).Value = rnum;
//...
```

// Thanks for BASOZ idea and help

```
var sql = string.Format(@"
select top 1 
    t1.assemblyno, t1.level, t1.wo_no, t1.rout_no, t1.due_date, t1.printed, t1.rev_no, t2.lot, t2.po, t2.qty_due, 
    t3.comment, t3.jobno, t3.order_val, t3.part_no,t3.po,t3.price, t3.qty_order,t3.quote_no, t3.rev_no 
from {2} t3
    inner join {1} t2 on t3.jobno = t2.jobno
    inner join {0} t1 on t1.wo_no = t2.wo_no 
    where t1.rout_no=?
        and t3.order_val in (
        SELECT max(tt3.order_val) 
                            FROM {0} tt1 
                            left join {1} tt2 
                                on tt1.wo_no = tt2.wo_no
                            left join {2} tt3 
                                on tt2.jobno = tt3.jobno
                            where tt1.rout_no = ?
                            group by tt1.rout_no
        )
        {3} {4}
        order by t3.jobno desc ", "t1", "t2", "t3", startCheck, endCheck);
```

Comment: I have tried to explain above. Excuse if not what is asked for.

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with DBF format. Your explanation doesn't tell much. Is jobno a primary key in 3rd table???? I guess no. Anyway did you try the code I have given already. You probably should give some sample data if not.

Comment: Additional information: Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword. I will try to trace this. I think I understating your approach from second LEFT JOIN

Comment: Abandon solution. I cannot figure out. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @busymind, what do you mean "abandon solution"? You first need to figure out what you are trying to do. You would do the max() in a subquery and match it to the rows you need.

Comment: I have added some extra explanation above, best I can. I have almost 10 hours working on this.

Comment: I don't see any extra explanation :( OK, let's do something that I wouldn't normally do. If you want to try this online using something like team viewer, send an email to Cetin dot Basoz at deu dot edu dot tr (sorry for giving email like that). If I get the email, maybe we can look into it after 3 PM EST.

Comment: Thank you I just sent you a mail.

Answer (score 0):

this would be true for all db formats not just foxpro - you asked for max of t3.order_val, but you didnt tell it how to pick the max the group by does that.. so

If you had a db of person_name, gender, age

you could find out the max age for each gender with `select gender, Max(age) from mytable group by gender`.

without the group by it doesnt know what to give you the max of what set of values?

Usually the group by is all the values you arent doing that sort of calculation on

Comment: I have added the group clause on my query but still somewhere is an error

Comment: Can you enter it in the order as above - while directly foxpro supports group by before where, the odbc or whatever drivers you are using may not.